# How to download csv data from a website using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm trying to learn how to get data from a website that loads data through some javascript into a table. For example, the website is [here](https://www.draftkings.com/contest/draftteam/22264509)

I used Selenium to get the data from the tables here. Here's the code

```
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
browser.get(url)     # using the page linked above

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                (By.ID, 'fancybox-outer')))

print("Page loaded")
browser.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//div[contains(@class, "tabs")]/ul/li[text() = "All"]').click()


data_table = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="grid-canvas"]')

for rows in data_table.find_elements_by_xpath(
            '//div[contains(@class, "slick-row")]'):
    row = rows.text.split('\n')
    print(row)
```

However, it only get the partial data since the data is loaded in the table dynamically as the table is scrolled. How do I get the data from the "All" table while taking care of the scrolling?

**There is also a "Export To CSV" Data button at the bottom that I could use to get the data I need, but a click() event on that button isn't giving me the csv data in the code. If possible, getting this csv would be better.**

Answer (score 2):

Let's aim to getting the CSV file. The problem is that `PhantomJS` does not deal well with file downloads, see [Download file via hyperlink in PhantomJS using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911395/download-file-via-hyperlink-in-phantomjs-using-selenium) (things might've changed though).

Anyway, let's grab the link to the CSV file and use [`urlretrieve()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) to download the file:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin  # for Python2: from urlparse import urljoin
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


url = "https://www.draftkings.com/contest/draftteam/22264509"
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
browser.get(url)

# wait for page to load
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'fancybox-outer')))
print("Page loaded")

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "tabs")]/ul/li[text() = "All"]').click()

# download the file
csv_url = urljoin(url, browser.find_element_by_css_selector("a.export-to-csv").get_attribute("href"))
urlretrieve(csv_url, "players.csv")
```

Comment: does it work for this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632860/python-selenium-web-scrape-embedded-excel-in-xpath-to-pandas-frame-convert-logic if this will work for sure my work is 80% done