# Automate blob URL download with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, blob, export-to-csv

I am trying to automate the download of a CSV file by using PhantomJS to click on an object on a website.

```
function() {
    (page.evaluate(function() {
        $("export2csv").click();
    }))
}
```

If I run this in the Chrome dev-console a CSV file starts downloading.
Chrome displays `blob:https://website/seeminglyrandomstring` as its source, which means I have no static URL pointing to this file.

If I run it in PhantomJS however, there is no output, just like it finished without any errors. But neither do I get my file.
Has this anything to to with the following statement in the official documentation?

> The execution is sandboxed, the web page has no access to the phantom object and it can’t probe its own setting.

I am using PhantomJS 2.0.0 on **Windows**

Comment: According to [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911395/download-file-via-hyperlink-in-phantomjs-using-selenium), phantomjs "would *never proceed with a download request*", so we can assume it doesn't support the download attribute. However, I don't know phantomjs that much and can't be 100% sure it's a duplicate, so I'll let someone with more experience to VTC.

Comment: I will try using Chromedriver with Python for Windows ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of PhantomJS's limitations, I will try using Chromedriver with Selenium for Python on Windows.

EDIT:

Heres a simple solution:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

#xenoid 18.01.2018


#Starting the driver
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

#Download directory
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "C:/temp/"}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
#Location to chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe', 
chrome_options=chromeOptions)
driver.get("_URL_TO_WEBSITE_");
#Time it takes for the website to load
time.sleep(5)
#Click the button
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("_YOUR_CSS_SELECTOR_'")
button.click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.quit()
```